# Calculating probability of obtaining exactly two $20$'s in $40$ rolls of a fair $20$-sided die

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I have a question:

> On a fair 20-sided die, the number $20$ comes up once every $20$ rolls. In forty rolls, it's expected that about two rolls of $20$ will happen.  What are the actual odds that, after forty rolls, there will be EXACTLY two rolls that come up $20$?

**What I did so far:** Since there are $40$ rolls, we choose $2$ of them to be $20$'s, which gives us $780$ ways to get $2 \times 20$'s arranged among $40$ rolls ($\binom{40}{2}$). Since there are $40$ rolls, we have a total of $20^{40}$ different combinations of rolls. Hence my derived answer is $780/(20^{40})$ which is wrong.

I'm not sure where I went wrong but I assume it's the way I'm calculating the number of combinations that have exactly $2 \times 20$'s. (Which should be $\binom{40}{2}$ no?)

Please help me understand where I went wrong and many thanks in advance.

Comment: The binomial distribution is your friend.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\binom{40}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{20}\right)^{2}\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{20}\right)^{40-2}\approx27.76\%$$

Comment: It's a self-explanatory answer, so I hope that it helps you to understand where you've gone wrong (but feel free to let me know otherwise).

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate on how you came up with the equation?

Comment: I only get the 40 choose 2 part, the rest is vague to me.

Comment: @ChristopherLeong: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution.

Comment: @ChristopherLeong: Step #1: Choose $2$ out of $40$ places for the specific result that you want (in this case, "20"). Step #2: The probability for each of these places to get that result is $\frac{1}{20}$, independently of each other. Since you need it it $2$ places, raise this probability to the power of $2$. Step #3: The remaining places can get any value **except** for your specific result (in this case, "1,...,19,21,...,40"). So there are $40-2$ remaining places, and the probability for each of them to get a "good value" is $1-\frac{1}{20}$... independently of each other... get it?

Comment: Yes I get it now, thank you.